# Проблема с кодом Discord ботом: AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'json'

Tags: python, discord-api

Очень нужна помощь, пытался сделать прогноз погоды, но компилятор игнорирует команду и выдает ошибку.

Ошибка в консоли:

```
discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command weather
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/GlaringSteepArchives/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 229, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 33, in weather
    response = requests.get(url).json()
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'json'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/GlaringSteepArchives/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/GlaringSteepArchives/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1023, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/runner/GlaringSteepArchives/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 238, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'json'
/nix/store/hd4cc9rh83j291r5539hkf6qd8lgiikb-python3-3.10.8/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py:80: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ClientSession._request' was never awaited
  self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Сам код:

```
   @bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')

@bot.command()
async def weather(ctx, *, city: str):
    url = f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid={WEATHER_API_KEY}&units=metric'
    response = requests.get(url).json()
    if response['cod'] == '404':
        await ctx.send(f'City "{city}" not found.')
    else:
        weather_desc = response['weather'][0]['description']
        temp = response['main']['temp']
        feels_like = response['main']['feels_like']
        humidity = response['main']['humidity']
        wind_speed = response['wind']['speed']
        weather_info = f'Weather in {city}: {weather_desc}\nTemperature: {temp}°C\nFeels like: {feels_like}°C\nHumidity: {humidity}%\nWind speed: {wind_speed} m/s'
        await ctx.send(weather_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить

```
response = requests.get(url).json()
```

На

```
response = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: Попробовал изменить, и снова ошибку выдает при вводе команды

Comment: discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command weather
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/GlaringSteepArchives/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 229, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 34, in weather
    if response['cod'] == '404':
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Comment: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ClientSession._request' was never awaited
  self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: Почему вы считаете что это поможет решить проблему?

Comment: @ΝNL993 ошибку внимательнее если посмотреть - response = requests.get(url).json()
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'json'

Comment: @AleksandrFetisov объяснение должно содержаться в ответе. Я не должен спрашивать у вас в комментариях вопросы подобные моему. В данном случае у вас получается такой ответ: этот ответ решит вашу проблему, потому что он решит вашу проблему. Да, может он кому-то и поможет, но не поможет разобраться в вопросе.

Comment: @ΝNL993 да окей) не вопрос